# Is stagnation pressure the limit on pressure you can get out of a flow without adding more energy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

I have a complex area of a pipe system where I'm not totally sure all that's going to be going on in terms of turbulence and compressible flow, though I would still like to verify that nothing in the area is going to be under too much pressure.

My thinking is that I can just calculate the stagnation pressure upstream at the inlet, where the geometry is much simpler. That way I know this is the max pressure any one area can experience without the addition of more energy. However I don't know if that line of thinking is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

No, total/stagnation pressure is not the maximum pressure possible. It is the pressure that can be reached by *isentropic* stagnation of the flow. Other changes of state, resulting in higher pressures, are possible.

Moreover, this depends on the other boundary conditions. Is your whole network on the same gravitational level, i.e. does the fluid have the same potential energy everywhere? Additionally, the fluid's energy can rise due to heat conduction through the pipes, although this energy source is usually much weaker than a pump or compressor.

However, the actual problem will be hydraulic shock or water hammer. If a valve is closed quickly, all of the fluid is decelerated, causing a shock wave. This pressure is much higher than the total/stagnation pressure.